# how to stop listing directories in powershell after you've entered dir -r?

Tags: powershell

i was trying to list the directories of my user but i didn't realize my current working directory was in c:/ and when i entered dir -r, powershell started to list every single directory on my drive! It's been going on for a long time now. How do i stop it?

Comment: (first post on stack overflow ever pls dont hate XD)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to stop commands.

You can also simply close the PowerShell prompt window.

Comment: omg tysm i tried ctrl + q cuz i heard it "quits" things but that didn't work

Comment: You're welcome. In most command line interface, including Windows, Linux, macOS, you can use Ctrl + C to stop a command.

Comment: Also note. If you hit Ctrl+c and it seems to not quit. It's ok to smash it a few times. But after that it's a waiting game. It depends on how far ahead of the display the command process is. Dir is easily quit. But bigger commands can take some time.